# Rotating blurred element in rotated plane is partially obscured in Chrome

Tags: css, 3d, rotation, blur, clip-path

I want to have a blurred polygon (let's say a triangle for simplicity) rotating in a 3D rotated plane.

I make the full height (`100vh`) `body` my scene and set perspective properties on it.

I use a `section` for the plane and a `div` inside for the blurred rotating item.

To get a polygon, I use `clip-path`, but since `filter` is applied *before* `clip-path`, I use a pseudo-element to get the actual polygon shape.

All is good until I put together the blur, the rotating animation of my `div` and the rotation of the plane.

I'm pretty sure this is a bug, since I'm only hitting it in Chrome. But the question is, how can I go around it now, not when it's going to eventually get fixed?

---

The only solution I've been able to find so far was to use, instead of a pseudo clipped with CSS `clip-path`, an SVG child with a polygon blurred using an SVG filter. But I'd like to know if there's a no SVG solution so I don't have to clutter up my markup.

```css
body {
  overflow: hidden;
  height: 100vh;
  perspective: 45vmin;
  perspective-origin: 50% 85%;
}

section {
  position: absolute;
  top: 50%;
  left: 50%;
  transform: rotatex(90deg); /* not buggy without this */
}

div {
  position: absolute;
  filter: blur(20px);  /* or without this */
  animation: r 8s linear infinite;  /* or without this */
}
div:before {
  position: absolute;
  margin: -20vmin;
  width: 40vmin;
  height: 40vmin;
  background: deeppink;
  clip-path: polygon(50% 0, 100% 100%, 0 100%);
  content: "";
}

@keyframes r {
  to {
    transform: rotate(1turn);
  }
}
```

```html
<section><div></div></section>
```

This is what I'm seeing in Chrome:

[image: screen recording]

Answer (score 0):

If I understand well, then try this:

```
  body {
  overflow: hidden;
  height: 100vh;
  perspective: 45vmin;
  perspective-origin: 50% 85%;
  -webkit-filter:blur(10px);
}
```

...

```
div {
  position: absolute;
  -webkit-filter:blur(10px);
   /* or without this */
  animation: r 8s linear infinite;  /* or without this */
}
```

...

https://codepen.io/catafest/pen/PvqJQE